# User.Identity.Name gives IIS server user name instead client user name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller, windows-authentication

In my MVC application I am tried to show domain/user on top right corner, it works well on visual studio with User.Identity.Name / Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name

When I host this on server it shows server_domain/server_username.

I have already put authentication mode = windows and impersonate true. Using ApplicationPoolIdentity and LoadUserProfile = true.

I know I need to put anonymous off and windows identity on. That I have already done. I have also edited my applicationHost.config and have made override allow for the authentication modes. I have removed lock for both in the same file.

My local domain and server domain is different though.

I am not understanding what am I missing/doing wrong. Can someone help me in this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get client user name.

also, make sure you have authorization tag in your system.web in web.config as

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/

Comment: Yeah that tag is also there but still facing the issue.

Comment: @Poonam could you please share your get username code and web.config file?